# Arguments of R Functions in Beamer with knitr

Tags: beamer, r, knitr

I'm using `helpExtract.R` function (can be obtained from [here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7586769)) to get arguments of `R` functions in `Beamer` with `knitr`. My (`.Rnw`) MWE is

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ragged2e}   %new code
\usetheme{default}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}  %new code
\addtobeamertemplate{knitrout begin}{}{\justifying}  %new code
\addtobeamertemplate{alltt begin}{}{\justifying}  %new code




<< label = setup, include = FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(size = 'footnotesize')
options(replace.assign = TRUE, width = 60)
@


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{Linear Model}

\begin{block}{lm}

<< label=lm-args, echo=FALSE, comment=NA>>=
str(args(lm))
@ 
\end{block}

\end{frame}



\begin{frame}[fragile]{Linear Model}

\begin{block}{lm function with testHelpExtract}

<< label = helpExtract-fn, echo = FALSE >>=
library(devtools)
source("helpExtract.R")
@


\Sexpr{knit_child(textConnection(helpExtract(lm, section="Usage", type = "s_code")), options = list(tidy = TRUE, echo=TRUE, eval = FALSE))}


\end{block}

\end{frame}



\begin{frame}[fragile]{Linear Model}

\begin{block}{lm function with testHelpExtract}

\Sexpr{knit_child(textConnection(helpExtract(lm, section="Arguments", type = "s_code")[1:15]), options = list(tidy = FALSE, echo=TRUE, eval = FALSE))}


\end{block}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{Linear Model}

\begin{block}{lm function with testHelpExtract}

\Sexpr{knit_child(textConnection(helpExtract(lm, section="Arguments", type = "s_code")[16:25]), options = list(tidy = FALSE, echo=TRUE, eval = FALSE))}


\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I've few issues with this MWE.

**Issues**

1. Could not justify the text in block.
2. Getting this error message, even though got output: Error message

   Error in parse(text = code) : :1:14: unexpected symbol 1: formula: an object ^

Any help to resolve these issues will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I know nothing about `knitr` nor `R` so I can't help much here, but you can only use `\addtobeamertemplate{<template name>}{}{}` with an already defined beamer template. While the `block begin` template is defined by the beamer class the `knitrout begin` is not, so the `\addtobeamertemplate{}{}{}` command has no effect there.